# Weird sAMAccountName when creating user account using DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices, adsi

my C# code uses the DirectoryServices namespace to create domain user accounts.

```
    DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=MYOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL");
    directoryEntry = deRoot.Children.Add("CN=Tony", "user");
    directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    directoryEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "Tony1";
    directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = "Tony Danza";
    directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", "mypass123");
    directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

This successfully creates the account but the sAMAccountName property contains a rather weird value like $HGA000-8FP94NQK9R9I or $NGA000-B3BJ2ELT5OOD.
When executed inside my dev-domain, everything's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the sAMAccountName before the first `CommitChanges`.

Maybe, since sAMAccountName is a required attribute, the system gives it a default value if you don't provide it when you create the object.

Comment: OMG, you're right. sAMAccountName has to be set BEFORE calling CommitChanges() for the first time. Keep in mind though, that this is not necessary when working in a Windows 2008 (R2) domain functional level.